# How can I make a stepline or stepped chart in chart.js or D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graphing, chart.js

I'm able to accomplish this in Google Spreadsheets, below is a screenshot:

[image: Google Spreadsheet Screenshot]

Here's the small dataset in CSV

```
Buy PPU,Sell PPU,Net PPU
0.023,0.019,-0.000725
0.026,0.0165,-0.003725
0.021,0.021,0.00735
0.015,0.0165,0.0147
0.021,0.028,0.0168
0.018,0.028,0.0198
```

- jsFiddle with basic configuration: http://jsfiddle.net/kaatula/j3FJf/1/
- Chart.js documentation: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/
- D3 documentation: http://strongriley.github.io/d3/api/

Any help is appreciated. I'm not seeing an example in either library of this specific kind of chart (called I believe "Stepped" or "Step line"), but I believe they are flexible enough to accomplish this?

Thank you

Answer (score 17):

Nobody seem to have answered this, but you can do that with chart.js by setting **steppedLine: true** in the dataset configuration.

```
var config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: "My dataset",
                data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()],
                steppedLine: true,
            }
   }
```

Comment: In chart.js 3.5.1 the property is stepped

Answer (score 11):

@Baz's answer is perfect for D3 version 3, but for anyone struggling to find similar resources for version 4 (the API changed pretty dramatically)..

The process now is to use `d3.curveStepAfter` instead.

[documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#user-content-curves)

[example](http://bl.ocks.org/emmasaunders/c25a147970def2b02d8c7c2719dc7502)

---

An alternative approach is using a line and manually setting the interpolator, eg, `d3.line().curve(d3.curveStepAfter)`

Comment: This is the correct answer for v4 - thank you.  Too bad there can't be multiple accepted answers - for different contexts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `d3.svg.line` and set the `line.interpolate` to either `step-before` or `step-after`.

Here is the documentation:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_interpolate

Here is an example:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4342190

Answer (score 0):

Chartjs provides the stepped line chart with the `stepped` property for various charts. For example, in the HTML document, add the canvas and with the id:

[html]

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

[index.js]

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

const data = {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [5, 4, 3, 6, 2, 3],
        borderColor: '#FF0000',
        borderWidth: 2,
        stepped: 'after',
    }]
}

const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The `stepped` could be any of `false`, `true`, `before`, `after`, `middle`. Please see the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/stepped.html) for more information.