# Curve Js - Force curve to become square

Tags: charts

In my image below, is it possible to make the first point remain 1 until the second point becomes zero? and the second point remains zero until the third point becomes 1. It could be done by passing the data as a square, but just asking perhaps there is a way to do so in Chart Js.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287448/how-can-i-make-a-stepline-or-stepped-chart-in-chart-js-or-d3) - use the following code for a stepped line graph.

```
var config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: "My dataset",
                data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()],
                steppedLine: true,
            }
   }
```